# How to fix the exception 'Invalid argument, not a string or column' while joining two dataframes in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join two dataframes:

df1, columns:

```
document_nbr, line_id, product_id, product_size, reference_nbr, local_cd, invoice_local_cost, invoice_delivery_id, created_by_id, transaction_ind, etl_tmst, record_created_tmst, record_updated_tmst, source_id, line_number, etl_date
```

Joining df1 with df2:

df2 columns:

```
document_nbr, line_id, variant_id, line_nbr as line_number
```

on columns:

```
df1.document_nbr = df2.document_nbr and df1.line_id == df2.line_id
```

Join type: `left`

I have a column `line_number` present in both the dataframes `df1` and `df1` and I want to drop same column from `df1` and select it from `df2`.

To do that, I wrote the below logic to select all the columns but `line_number` from `df1` and select `line_number` from `df2`

```
df1 = df1.join(df2.alias('df2'),
    on=(df1.document_nbr == df2.document_nbr) & (df1.line_id == df2.line_id),
    how='left').\
    select([col(c) for c in df1.columns if c != 'line_number'], col("df2.line_number"))
```

When I run the code, I get the exception:

```
    Invalid argument, not a string or column: [Column<b'document_nbr'>, Column<b'line_id'>, Column<b'product_id'>, Column<b'product_size'>, Column<b'reference_nbr'>, Column<b'local_cd'>, Column<b'invoice_local_cost'>, Column<b'invoice_delivery_id'>, Column<b'created_by_id'>, Column<b'transaction_ind'>, Column<b'etl_tmst'>, Column<b'record_created_tmst'>, Column<b'record_updated_tmst'>, Column<b'source_id'>, Column<b'source_id'>,Column<b'etl_date'>] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local_disk0/tmp/spark-14a2e8a1-b280-4c83-a724-16976b1bc277/template_python-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl/src/line_upd.py", line 66, in line_transformation
    how='left').select([col(c) for c in df1.columns if c != 'line_number'], col("df2.line_number"))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1439, in select
    jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1233, in _jcols
    return self._jseq(cols, _to_java_column)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1220, in _jseq
    return _to_seq(self.sql_ctx._sc, cols, converter)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 68, in _to_seq
    cols = [converter(c) for c in cols]
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 68, in <listcomp>
    cols = [converter(c) for c in cols]
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 56, in _to_java_column
    "function.".format(col, type(col)))
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here ? How can I select all columns but `line_number` from `df1` abd column `line_number` from `df2` after the join ?

Comment: The question aint as clear. See what I have done below. Happy to assist further

Answer (score 1):

Just drop it after join

```
df1 = df1.join(df2.alias('df2'),
    on=(df1.document_nbr == df2.document_nbr) & (df1.line_id == df2.line_id),
    how='left').drop(df1.line_number).show()
```

With Sample data

```
df1=spark.createDataFrame([(100     ,   'QC'    ,     'Darzalex MM'),
(105    ,    'XY'    ,     'INVOKANA'),
(107     ,   'CZ'    ,     'Simponi  RA'),
(117     ,   'NM'     ,    'Guselkumab PSA'),
(118    ,    'YC'     ,    'STELARA'),
(126    ,    'RF'      ,   'INVOKANA')],
 ('document_nbr' ,   'line_id'  ,  'line_number'))

df1.show()

df2  =spark.createDataFrame([(118     ,  'YC'    ,    'STELARA'),
(126    ,    'RF'    ,     'INVOKANA'),
(131    ,    'VG'   ,     'STELARA'),
(135     ,   'IJ'   ,      'Stelara CD')],
 ('document_nbr' ,   'line_id' ,   'line_number'))

df2.show() 

df1 = df1.join(df2.alias('df2'),
    on=(df1.document_nbr == df2.document_nbr) & (df1.line_id == df2.line_id),
    how='left').drop(df1.line_number).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use select after the join to select the columns you need using aliases

```
new_df= df1.alias('df1').join(df2.alias('df2'),
    on=(df1.document_nbr == df2.document_nbr) & (df1.line_id == df2.line_id),
    how='left').select('df1.document_nbr', 'df1.line_id', 'df2.line_number')
```

New_Df will now have only 3 columns, but you can add as many as you like.If you want to add all columns from a df use 'df1.*'. Hope this helps!